# Double Click On JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a bit of trouble with this. So my company wants a left drawer menu for app. Specifically the control for the menu is attached too each individual row. i.e. each row has order separate order numbers and a Actions button attached. When Action button is clicked drawer opens for various actions. Now the problem is, the first and only the first click requires two clicks. One click can be any where on the page. 2nd click required to activate the drawer. After 2nd click it closes, and re opens smoothly with one click. So why the first 2 clicks?

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(event){    
        $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
            $('.slideout-menu-toggle').unbind();
            event.preventDefault();
            // create menu variables
            var slideoutMenu = $('body');
            var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

            // toggle open class
            slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

            // slide menu
            if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
                slideoutMenu.animate({
                    left: "0px"
                }); 
            } else {
                slideoutMenu.animate({
                    left: -slideoutMenuWidth
                }, 278);

            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You are binding a click event handler inside another click event handler. The first click binds the handler, the second click triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

The first click needs to happen in order for `.slide-menu-toggle` to receive it's bind.

```
...
$(document).on('click', function(event){    // first click
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){ // menu click added
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to `return false` in first click function

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){        
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
     //code here
    })
    return false;
})
```